# How to enable "MySQL in App" in an App Service using the Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I have created an App Service in Azure using the CLI. But, I cannot see any CLI options to enable "MySQL in App". I have checked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest and see no mention of it.

What is the CLI to enable it? Or, failing that, if there is no CLI command, using PowerShell?

Comment: Incorrect. "MySQL in App" has been around since 2016. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/mysql-in-app-preview-app-service/ Moreover - I'm using it so I know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your question is related to az cli but I don't know if possible using that myself.
I can confirm however that the following works using PowerShell (Az module):

```
$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <Resource Group Name> -Name <Web App Name>
$app.SiteConfig.LocalMySqlEnabled = $true
$app | Set-AzWebApp
```

Hope this helps until someone can confirm for az cli specifically.

Comment: Thank you @killercowuk. I will give that a try.